# Cause of engine oil and coolant mixing in head tank of Vauxhall Zafira

Tags: vauxhall, zafira, oil-in-coolant, oil-cooler

I have a Vauxhall Zafira elite (2008) which has overheated and I noticed oil in the coolant in the head tank. Would a malfunctioning oil cooler cause oil and water to mix in the engine?

Answer (score 3):

> Would a malfunctioning oil cooler cause oil and water to mix in the engine?

*Possibly* - but it's pretty unlikely. Nine out of ten times this is going to be a blown head gasket I'm afraid.

Comment: I don't think if oil/water are mixing the oil cooler is something you should discount (check easiest things first). *However*, considering there was also an overheat involved, I believe your probability of 90% of the time the head gasket being the issue is probably a bit low.